# JavaScript => operator

Tags: javascript

I was looking at some [frontend guidelines](https://github.com/bendc/frontend-guidelines) on GitHub and saw the following code sample:

```
// good
const createDivs = howMany => {
  if (!howMany) return;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div></div>");
  return createDivs(howMany - 1);
};
createDivs(5);
```

What does the `=>` do and what is it called? I have never seen this idiom before. I tried looking it up but do not know its name and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) does not show it.

Comment: It's being implemented in ECMA6. `howMany => {}` is a shorhand for `function howMany () {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MDN documentation on [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions:

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value. Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Besides the fact that they are a more concise way of writing an anonymous function, arrow functions have the benefit of binding `this` in the function expression. Thus, the pattern typically used with `bind`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function myHandler (event) {
    console.log(event);
}.bind(this));
```

becomes

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => console.log(event));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's a shorter way of writing a function expression.

This example from Mozilla illustrates the advantage of defining a function with an arrow expression:

```
var a = [
  "Hydrogen",
  "Helium",
  "Lithium",
  "Beryl­lium"
];

var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

Observe that `s => s.length` is shorter than the traditional equivalent `function(s){ return s.length }`. It will be easier to read, too, once we get used to seeing this form.